# XML Row TYPE (xml data input)

Tags: xml, database, oracle, xsd, xmltype

Step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
idCustomer INT PRIMARY KEY,
XmlCustomer XMLTYPE not null);
```

Step 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDIR AS 'C:\xml_files';
```

Step 3:

XmlCustomer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XmlCustomer>
     <Customer>
        <name>Sally Black</name>
        <type>Person</type>
        <nip>1234567890</nip>
        <city>London</city>
        <street>Blue Street 2</street>
        <signUpDate>21-12-2007</signUpDate>
     </Customer>
     <Customer>
        <name>John Snow</name>
        <type>Person</type>
        <nip>2345678901</nip>
        <city>Wroclaw</city>
        <street>Uprised 23</street>
        <signUpDate>12-02-1991</signUpDate>
     </Customer>
     <Customer>
        <name>PC-Kom</name>
        <type>Fleet</type>
        <nip>3456789012</nip>
        <city>Swidnica</city>
        <street>Water Street 5</street>
        <signUpDate>12-02-1991</signUpDate>
     </Customer>
</XmlClient>
```

Step 4:

now im trying to input those XMLdata into Table Customer

```
INSERT INTO Customer (idCustomer,XmlCustomer) VALUES (1, XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'XmlCustomer.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

but im inserting all file into 1 ROW.
My question is how to insert those data to receive 3 ROWs (xml file contains 3 rows)
and how to auto incremet idCustomer??

Also i need to create xsd:schema of this xml file and thats kinda black magic for me ^^.

Im quite new with Oracle DB and XML, so im waiting for stright answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm), and more specifically here `XMLTable`, to convert the XML document into multiple values you can treat as rows:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (idCustomer, xmlCustomer)
SELECT CustomerIdSeq.nextval, XmlCustomer
FROM XMLTable('/XmlCustomer/Customer'
  PASSING XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'XmlCustomer.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  COLUMNS "XMLCUSTOMER" XMLType PATH '/'
);
```

I've created [a sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/pseudocolumns002.htm) and I'm calling `nextval` for that to generate the 'auto-increment' customer IDs; Oracle 12c has auto-increment columns but in earlier versions you need a sequence to fake that, optionally with a trigger to hide it. Anyway, that gives:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY idCustomer;

IDCUSTOMER XMLCUSTOMER
---------- ---------------------------------------------------
         1 <Customer>
              <name>Sally Black</name>
              <type>Person</type>
              <nip>1234567890</nip>
              <city>London</city>
              <street>Blue Street 2</street>
              <signUpDate>21-12-2007</signUpDate>
           </Customer>

         2 <Customer>
              <name>John Snow</name>
              <type>Person</type>
              <nip>2345678901</nip>
              <city>Wroclaw</city>
              <street>Uprised 23</street>
              <signUpDate>12-02-1991</signUpDate>
           </Customer>

         3 <Customer>
              <name>PC-Kom</name>
              <type>Fleet</type>
              <nip>3456789012</nip>
              <city>Swidnica</city>
              <street>Water Street 5</street>
              <signUpDate>12-02-1991</signUpDate>
           </Customer>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb4b29) is happy to create populate that, but struggles querying it as plain XML...

Unless you particularly want to store the XML constructs, you might be better off creating individual columns and loading the data into those:

```
SELECT CustomerIdSeq.nextval, name, type, nip, city, street, signUpDate
FROM XMLTable('/XmlCustomer/Customer'
  PASSING XMLType(bfilename('D42', 'XmlCustomer.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  COLUMNS "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'name',
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'type'
    "NIP" NUMBER PATH 'nip'
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'city'
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'street'
    "SIGNUPDATE" DATE PATH 'signUpDate'
);
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (idCustomer, name, type, nip, city, street, signUpDate)
SELECT CustomerIdSeq.nextval, name, type, nip, city, street,
  TO_DATE(signUpDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM XMLTable('/XmlCustomer/Customer'
  PASSING XMLType(bfilename('D42', 'XmlCustomer.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  COLUMNS "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'name',
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'type',
    "NIP" NUMBER PATH 'nip',
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'city',
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'street',
    "SIGNUPDATE" VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'signUpDate'
);
```

Which gives:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer ORDER BY idCustomer;

IDCUSTOMER NAME                 TYPE              NIP CITY                 STREET               SIGNUPDATE
---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         4 Sally Black          Person     1234567890 London               Blue Street 2        21-DEC-07  
         5 John Snow            Person     2345678901 Wroclaw              Uprised 23           12-FEB-91  
         6 PC-Kom               Fleet      3456789012 Swidnica             Water Street 5       12-FEB-91
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa398/1).

You'd need to set suitable sizes for the string columns, of course. Notice that I've used `to_date()` to convert the date string into an actual date; since it isn't in the standard YYYY-MM-DD ISO format [XML expects](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) it can't be extracted directly as a date value.

Comment: OK first idea is better option for me still i have a problem:
error: Line 2 Col:31
XMLCustomer: invalid identifier

in
INSERT INTO Customer (idCustomer, xmlCustomer)
SELECT CustomerIdSeq.nextval, XmlCustomer
FROM XMLTable('/XmlCustomer/Customer'
  PASSING XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'XmlCustomer.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  COLUMNS "XMLCUSTOMER" XMLType PATH '/'
);

Comment: @MatuRco - mm, that works for me in 11gR2, what version are you using? It doesn't seem to like the XML column name - not sure if that's a case issue.

Comment: Oracle 11g2R version x64 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html

Comment: Actually, which client are you using - that error is odd, it has `XMLCustomer: invalid identifier` which suggests the name is being quoted - but it isn't, unless your client is doing it under the hood?